# Contexto 'this' do EventEmitter<string> não é atribuível ao método 'this' do tipo Observable<string>

Tags: javascript, angular, aplicação-web, typescript, single-page-application

Olhei o exemplo em um repositório do GitHub. A aplicação executa com sucesso e o código escrito funciona normalmente, mas estou com o seguinte erro no meu Visual Studio Code:

> The 'this' context of type 'EventEmitter' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable'.\n  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.\n    Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.\n      Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.\n        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'.

O código que está gerando o erro é o seguinte:

```
this.notificationService.notifier
    .do(message => {
      this.message = message;
      this.snackVisibility = 'visible'; 
    })
    .switchMap(message => Observable.timer(2000))
    .subscribe(timer => this.snackVisibility = 'hidden');
```

Apesar de a aplicação funcionar perfeitamente o VS Code me apresenta o erro como apresentado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a melhor solução para este erro?

Comment: Se puder colocar o código do seu `this.notificationService.notifier`, por gentileza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de fazer algumas pesquisas, entendi que EventEmitter é utilizado de um Child par aum Parent. Para fazer comunicações de serviços para o componente é necessário utilizar o Subject.

Então o código do componente ficou assim:

```
this.notificationService.notifier$
                        .subscribe(message => {
                          this.message = message;
                          this.snackVisibility ='visible';
                          setTimeout(() => {
                            this.snackVisibility = 'hidden';
                          }, 2000);
                        });
```

E o código do serviço ficou assim:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

export class NotificationService {
    private notifier = new Subject<string>();
    public notifier$ = this.notifier.asObservable();

    notify(message: string) {
        this.notifier.next(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu service deve ter algo desse tipo:

```
notifier = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Uma outra solução pode ser você trocar de **string** para **any**, pois "nesse cenário", faz sentido.

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
notifier = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Um abraço!